# Что нужно чтобы построить робота?

Tags: робототехника

Что нужно знать? Что нужно использовать? Какие есть готовые конструкции, которые помогут в разработке своего робота, хотя бы простейшего, который делает одну функцию.

Comment: Неплохо бы начать с изучения форумов и сайтов по `arduino`.

Comment: а что такое arduino?

Comment: за сколько месяцев после начала изучения можно сделать что нибудь свое?

Comment: да, я посмотрел уже..просто как то автоматически получилось=)то что задал этот вопрос=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы все таки не советовал бы связываться с `arduino`, просто считаю его пустой тратой денег и сил, ибо знаний в области микроконтроллеров и программирования для них он дает мало (ИМХО). Лучше полазить по форуму http://roboforum.ru/, потом приобрести недорогой камешек (микроконтроллер), макетную плату + немного рассыпухи на обвязку и начать играться с ним. Думаю больше проблем будет с изготовлением всякой механики, многие бросают на этом этапе :). Так вам проще будет понять суть всего, а если затянет то вы будете уже на верном пути.